# trying to simulate pspice but there "Invalid value Circuit has errors ... run aborted See output file for details Simulation aborted"

Tags: schematics, pspice

i'm just start learning how to use pspice but during quarantine day is hard to ask my lecturer, hope u guys help me to fix this
this is output

```
**** 09/10/20 10:28:31 *********** Evaluation PSpice (Nov 1999) **************

 * C:\Users\Wafi Jailani\Desktop\New folder (6)\sem 3 2020\DEE30071 - puan rogayah\PW2 10.9.2020.sch


 ****     CIRCUIT DESCRIPTION


******************************************************************************

* Schematics Version 9.1 - Web Update 1
* Thu Sep 10 10:28:27 2020

** Analysis setup **
.tran 10us 300ns 0 600us
-----------$
ERROR -- Invalid value
.OP 


* From [PSPICE NETLIST] section of pspiceev.ini:
.lib "nom.lib"

.INC "PW2 10.9.2020.net"

**** INCLUDING "PW2 10.9.2020.net" ****
* Schematics Netlist *

R_R1         Vin $N_0001  1k  
Q_Q1         $N_0003 $N_0002 $N_0004 Q2N2222
C_C2         $N_0003 Vout  10u  
R_R6         0 Vout  10k  
R_R4         0 $N_0004  500  
R_R3         0 $N_0002  5.5k  
R_R2         $N_0002 $N_0005  30k  
C_C1         $N_0001 $N_0002  10u  
V_v1         $N_0005 0 0V
R_R5         $N_0003 $N_0005  2k  
C_C3         0 $N_0004  100u  
V_v2         Vin 0  
+SIN 0 1mV 10kHz 0 0 0

**** RESUMING "PW2 10.9.2020.cir" ****
.INC "PW2 10.9.2020.als"

**** INCLUDING "PW2 10.9.2020.als" ****
* Schematics Aliases *

.ALIASES
R_R1            R1(1=Vin 2=$N_0001 )
Q_Q1            Q1(c=$N_0003 b=$N_0002 e=$N_0004 )
C_C2            C2(1=$N_0003 2=Vout )
R_R6            R6(1=0 2=Vout )
R_R4            R4(1=0 2=$N_0004 )
R_R3            R3(1=0 2=$N_0002 )
R_R2            R2(1=$N_0002 2=$N_0005 )
C_C1            C1(1=$N_0001 2=$N_0002 )
V_v1            v1(+=$N_0005 -=0 )
R_R5            R5(1=$N_0003 2=$N_0005 )
C_C3            C3(1=0 2=$N_0004 )
V_v2            v2(+=Vin -=0 )
_    _(Vin=Vin)
_    _(Vout=Vout)
.ENDALIASES


**** RESUMING "PW2 10.9.2020.cir" ****
.probe


.END
```

.

Comment: Try a simpler example first and then add stuff back in.

Comment: Does PSpice allow `us` in the `.tran` card? Try removing them, i.e. don't add units: `2uF`, or `3nH`, and such, just leave `2u` or `3n`.